# Understanding the gradient descent method as applied to a specific quadratic problem

Tags: convex-optimization, gradient-descent

The following example of the gradient descent method is given in section 9.3.2 on pp. 469-470 of Boyd and Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization* (Cambridge University Press, 2009).

Let $\gamma > 0$, and consider the following objective function on $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+\gamma x_2^2).
$$

According to Boyd and Vandenverghe, applying the gradient descent method with exact line search, starting at $x^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix}\gamma\\1\end{bmatrix}$, the following closed-form expressions for the iterates $x^{(k)}$ ensue:
$$
x_1^{(k)} = \gamma\bigg(\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma+1}\bigg)^k,\qquad x_2^{(k)} = \bigg(-\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma+1}\bigg)^k.\tag{*}
$$

However, when I try to derive the expression for $x_1^{(1)}$ and $x_2^{(1)}$ I get different expressions than those appearing in $(*)$. Here's my derivation. I'd appreciate it if someone could point out where my error lies.

We can write $f$ as $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx$, where $A := \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\gamma\end{bmatrix}$, showing that $f$ is a quadratic form. Hence,
$$
\Delta x = -\nabla f(x) = -Ax = \begin{bmatrix}-x_1\\-\gamma x_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
f(x+s\Delta x) &= f(x-sAx)\\
&= f(\begin{bmatrix}x_1(1-s)\\x_2(1-\gamma s)\end{bmatrix})\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\big(x_1(1-s)\big)^2 + \gamma\big(x_2(1-\gamma s)\big)^2\bigg)\\
&= \frac{x_1^2(\gamma^3+1)}{2}s^2 -x_1^2(\gamma^2+1)s + \frac{x_1^2(\gamma+1)}{2}
\end{align*}

Hence $t = \text{argmin}_{s\geq0}f(x+s\Delta x)$ is the root of the derivative of the function
$$
s\mapsto \frac{x_1^2(\gamma^3+1)}{2}s^2 -x_1^2(\gamma^2+1)s + \frac{x_1^2(\gamma+1)}{2},
$$
namely $t = \frac{\gamma^2+1}{\gamma^3+1}$.

Hence,
\begin{align*}
x^{(1)} &= x^{(0)} + t\Delta x^{(0)}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}\gamma\\1\end{bmatrix} + \frac{\gamma^2+1}{\gamma^3+1}\begin{bmatrix}-\gamma\\-\gamma\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}\gamma\big(1-\frac{\gamma^2+1}{\gamma^3+1}\big)\\1-\gamma\frac{\gamma^2+1}{\gamma^3+1}\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
x_1^{(1)} &= \gamma\big(1-\frac{\gamma^2+1}{\gamma^3+1}\big)\\
&= \gamma\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma+1}\cdot\frac{\gamma^2}{\gamma^2-\gamma+1}\\
x_2^{(2)}&= 1-\gamma\frac{\gamma^2+1}{\gamma^3+1}\\
&= \frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma+1}\cdot\frac{1}{\gamma^2-\gamma+1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Your expression for $f(x+s\Delta x)$, the last line, i don't follow it. Where did $x_2$ go?

Comment: @TSF: Oh, you're right! Maybe that is the error! Thanks.